# How to make curve using clipRect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

How to make green curve part using ClipRect which is below appbar. This is the white container below the green-colored.

I want to make this using cliprect.

[image]

When I use list of data that or image, then that data going from green color like this.

[image]

I want that my all data go under from green color.

This is my code.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: appGreenColor,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: appGreenColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "lib/Assets/dicon.png",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            height: 40,
            width: 78,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset(
                  "lib/Assets/notification1.png",
                  height: 22,
                  width: 22,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => NotificationList()));
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 70,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(28), topRight: Radius.circular(28))),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    locationView(),
                    imageSlider(),
                    genderView(),
                    categories(),
                    isMan == true
                        ? maleTopBranches.length == 0
                            ? Container()
                            : topRatedSalons(maleTopBranches)
                        : topRatedSalons(femaleTopBranches),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              offerImage(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    services(),
                    nearByAppointment(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              infoImage()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. I have try your image like code.

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.greenAccent,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 80,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                topRight: Radius.circular(60),
              ),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Add your Other widgets here',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your resukt screen-> [image]

Comment: no it did not work it's work like that.

Comment: What do you want